# Google Assistant - Action not approved

Tags: actions-on-google

I have recently create an action and tested it in web simulator and on my Pixel 2 device. It is working fine for me. But during the review process the team at Google mentioned that while reviewing they found that error saying that my app isn't responding right now. Try again soon. (Screenshot attached). Can someone from the community please assist me on how to resolve the issue.

Below is the code in fullfillment, if this helps.

```
    'use strict';

    // Import the Dialogflow module from the Actions on Google client library.
    const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');

    // Import the firebase-functions package for deployment.
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');

    // Instantiate the Dialogflow client.
    const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

    // Handle the Dialogflow intent named 'favorite color'.
    // The intent collects a parameter named 'color'.
    app.intent('think number', (conv, {nextStep}) => {
        conv.close('The result is 9.');
    });

    // Set the DialogflowApp object to handle the HTTPS POST request.
    exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

**Screenshot of the response from Review Team**:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes they are a bit quick to reject if there are network problems between them and Dialogflow, or if Dialogflow isn't responding. Make sure you turn on Dialogflow's logs to make sure there is no problem.

In general, the easiest thing to do if you haven't seen any errors and things appear to be working on your end is to:

1. Resubmit
2. Reply and tell them that you're using Dialogflow and there should be a reply.

Comment: Accepted the answer as it was some issue from their end. The same implementation has been approved the next time I submitted it.